# How to use separate database on differrent server with different username and password in wordpress for users data

Tags: database

How to use separate database with differrent server adresses, with different username and password on wordpress for users login data data, and be able to use it on 2 wordpress installs, but with separate permissions but with shared login.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this can be done on a separate sever hosts but if you have two websites that are on different URLs but hosted on the same server host this can be done with using the same database and using different prefix for each install.

This link will show you how.
[share users](http://www.remicorson.com/share-users-database-on-different-wordpress-installs/)

Comment: I need it on separate hosts, and also to have shared login session

Comment: I think the link I sent shows how to do shared session but not sure you are able to do this across hosting providers I could be wrong.